# How to make a void method that will remove and replace duplicates from integer array in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to remove duplicates from an int array in Java. This method is void and should only alter the array I'm given. I'm also supposed to replace each duplicate with 0.

```
//array's duplicates are replaced with zero
//array is returned
public static void removeDuplicates(int[] array) {
    //create a temp variable to compare all other other int values in result array
    int temp;
    //double for loop iterates through array and compares each value to temp.
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        temp = array[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if ((array[j] == temp) && (j+1 < array.length)) {
                array[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried so far. It runs, however, I'm not able to replace all of my duplicates with zero. For example, if I have an array {2,2}, then I'll get an array {0,2} which is not what I want. Rather, I should be getting {0,0}. I've tried drawing this out and still can't find the problem.

Comment: Why does your 'if' statement intentionally refuse to replace the last element of the array?

Comment: You need to show a more complex example.  What is the expected contents of `int[] v = {1,2,3,2,4,5,6,2,8,9,9,10,11};` after it is processed?

Comment: @ undefined symbol I was getting an out of bounds exception if I didn't

Comment: @WJS int[] v should change to {1,0,3,0,4,5,6,0,8,0,0,10,11}. However, in the test arrays I'm given, there's only one number that's being repeated. So I don't think I'll have two different repeating numbers (the 2 and 9) as in your example.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem, I'm not sure where your thinking array[I] = 0 should go. Do you mean inside my if statement? Also, how does this help?

Comment: re *I was getting an out of bounds exception if I didn't*  No you weren't.  You can't possibly have. (1) j only ranges up to length-1 anyway, (2) that 'j+1 < length' phrase only prevents you accessing the j'th element **which you have already accessed**.

Comment: Meanwhile, your code has another bug - when the above 'j+1<length' problem is fixed, you'll be replacing all elements by zero, since there's nothing that avoids it.

Answer (score 1):

Temp holds the value(s) to be deleted but only if it is a duplicate. The inner loop must go from i+1 to the end to see if other values of `temp` exist.  If so, zero them out.  But since the first one is also equal to `temp` it must be deleted too if it was a duplicate.

Change your loops to the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
     temp = array[i];
     for(int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
         if (array[j] == temp) {
             array[j] = 0;
             array[i] = 0; // remove the first one too
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: This works! Thank WJS. However, I'm a little confused as to why you have array.length - 1 in the first for loop. Is this preventing the out of bounds exception I was running into?

Comment: @A_K_A think about it. What is the point of taking the _very last_ number in your array and checking if any further elements in the array are a duplicate of it?

Comment: I see now. There are no other elements to check after the last one. Thank you for the  clarification @rzwitserloot